# How to work on a new git branch while previous branch waits for merge

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-squash

First, I am sorry to ask such question because I am sure it is a straightforward issue, still I found no solution an no way to understand what I am doing wrong. Some people asked almost exactly the same question (except the squash part) and the answer was obvious (`rebase`) but does not work for me.

I create a branch A, multiple commits, then I submit a merge request A->develop, with commit squash on.

While I wait for the MR to be accepted, I want to work on a new issue, from the branch A. So I create a branch B from branch A.

At some point branch A got merged into develop, and all the commit from A squashed into a single commit in develop.

Once my work on B is finished, I create a new MR B -> develop. But I can't because develop has been updated with changes from A.  As I already have these changes in my branch B, because I created B from A, it should not be an issue. But it is.

No matter what I do from B:

```
git merge develop
```

or:

```
git rebase develop
```

I get an endless list of fake conflicts.

I suspect the issue is that the commit logs on my branch B includes all old commits of the branch A, whereas develop includes only one single squashed commit of the branch A. So they are not seen as the same commits and I get conflicts even though there are no actual conflicts. But I have no solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `git rebase --interactive` and manually edit out the commits from "A". Or if you still have your local branch "A" with the individual commits `git rebase --onto develop A B`, meaning: rebase all in B, since A onto develop

Comment: Looks great, I will try it next time. I have to say my knowledge of rebase was way too basic, after your answer I spent some time studying it, things are much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are trying to rebase all commits `develop..A` again on top of the merge-commit of develop and A.

Best is to use `rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto develop $last_commit_of_A B
```

Or run without `--onto` and then execute `git rebase --skip` for those already-merged commits.

Or use an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i develop B`) and delete (or change action to "drop") the lines that were already merged as part of A.